# C - Reading sentences from file into malloc created array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, file, malloc

I will be short on what is the problem:

I created an array of strings using malloc.
Now, I want to put sentences from a txt file into these strings.
I do not get any error, but when I want to print out the strings after the "read-in", it is just blank, there are no sentences at all.

I link the code of the program related to this.

Where did I make a mistake?

Please help.

Thanks!

EDIT: I got the problem.

```
questions[i]=(char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Is only allocates 1 byte.
The question now is the following: HOW should I allocate more bytes then?
These 'question[i]'s should be as 'long' as the sentence in it, said the teacher, but I do not know how to accomplish that.

```
char** questions
int numbofquestions=40;

questions=(char**) malloc(sizeof(char*)*numbofquestions);
int i;
for(i=0;i<numbofquestions;i++)
{
 questions[i]=(char*) malloc(sizeof(char));
}

FILE* fp;
fp=fopen("sentences.txt", "r");
for(i=0;i<4;i++) // LESS THAN 4 BECAUSE IT IS JUST A TEST, THERE IS ONLY 4 SENTENCES IN THE FILE AT THE MOMENT. EACH SENTENCE IS IN A DIFFERENT ROW.
{
 fgets(questions[i],sizeof(char),fp);
 printf("%s\n", questions[i]);
}
fclose(fp);

free(questions);
for(i=0;i<numbofquestions;i++)
{
 free(questions[i]);
}
```

Comment: `questions[i]=(char*) malloc(sizeof(char));` allocates 1 byte.  Seems a bit small.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is `1`. So `fgets(questions[i],sizeof(char),fp);` hold one charactor (NUL terminator). `fgets` can't read from file.

Comment: When given a single character buffer, `fgets()` can only store the null terminator.  You need to allocate more space per string, or read the line into a big string and then duplicate (`strdup()` instead of the original `malloc()` is easiest; you could use `realloc()` since you already did `malloc()` for each string) the line into the stored string.

Comment: I assume your questions are more than 1 character long?  (zero long actually) `questions[i]=(char*) malloc(sizeof(char));` would be wrong then.   (You might actually do better find the size of the question file, `malloc`ing that, read the whole file into that buffer, then setting your pointers into that. It wouldn't be zero terminated strings.  But you could clobber line-ends with zeros to get that)

Comment: Hey guys! Thanks all of you for your answers! I see, so I only allocated 1 byte there. That is indeed pretty bad. Although, can you guys tell me, how should i allocate more bytes then? I mean, the sentences have different lengths, so that is pretty problemastic. My teacher said that these 'questions[i]' -s should be as 'long' in bytes as the stored sentence in it. How should I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three mistakes.

```
malloc(sizeof(char))
```

,

```
fgets(questions[i],sizeof(char),fp);
```

and sequence of

```
free(...)
```

[1]:

```
int maxLengthOfString = 128; // or more.
...
(char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * maxLengthOfString);
```

because

```
sizeof(char) // == just 1 byte == 1 character == only '\0' in string.
```

[2]:

```
fgets(questions[i], sizeof(char) * maxLengthOfString, fp);
```

same reason as [1].

[3]:

```
for(i=0; i<numbofquestions; i++)
{
    free(questions[i]);
}
free(questions);
```

free(...) must in reverse order on this situation.

Comment: Hey!
Thank you for your answer!
it helps! :) 
May I ask you, that if I do not know the length of all of my sentences obviously, then what 'maxLengthOfString' should be in order to be able to store all of my sentences regardless of their length?

Comment: maxLengthOfString is just big enough.

Comment: Tried it. it Works. I mark you as a solution. HUGE THANKS for the fast and correct answer! Have a nice day!

Comment: ;) Have a nice day~

Comment: don't cast the result of malloc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc